# How to transform `chrono::format::strftime` to `chrono::format::Item` statically?

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

I have a static array of `chrono::format::strftime` formats that my application supports.
I'd like to avoid parsing them during run time, so I defined a `lazy_static!` block that parses them to a collection of `chrono::format::Item`.

However, when I try to iterate over the parsed collection, I'm getting an error:

```
the trait bound `&chrono::format::StrftimeItems<'_>: std::iter::Iterator` is not satisfied
```

Here's a short reproduction:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;
extern crate chrono;
use chrono::DateTime;
use chrono::offset::FixedOffset;
use chrono::format::{Parsed, parse};
use chrono::format::strftime::StrftimeItems;

static FORMATS : &[&'static str] = &["%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%.f"];

lazy_static! {
    static ref PARSED_FORMATS : Vec<StrftimeItems<'static>> = FORMATS
        .iter()
        .map(|format| StrftimeItems::new(format))
        .collect();
}

fn parse_datetime(s: &str) -> Option<DateTime<FixedOffset>> {
    for format in PARSED_FORMATS.iter() {
        let mut parsed = Parsed::new();
        let dt = parse(&mut parsed, &s, format)
            .and_then(|_| parsed.to_datetime() );
        if dt.is_ok() {
            return dt.ok()
        }
    }
    return None
}
```

Attempting to de-reference `format` in the loop gives this error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src\main.rs:21:35
   |
21 |         let dt = parse(&mut parsed, &s, *format)
   |                                         ^^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Attempting to clone `format` seems to work, however cloning seems redundant here and I'd like to avoid it.

Is this the right approach here? or perhaps using a macro is better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StrftimeItems` is an iterator, not an iterable container (like `Vec` is). When you advance an iterator, you can't rewind it. `parse` must receive an iterator by value, which means that you must take a `StrftimeItems` our of your vector (which means you can't reuse it afterwards) or clone the `StrftimeItems` stored in the vector. By cloning the `StrftimeItems`, you can produce a new iterator whose state is distinct from the original (i.e. advancing one doesn't advance the other).

> I'd like to avoid parsing them during run time

However, `StrftimeItems` doesn't let you achieve your goal, because [`StrftimeItems` lazily parses the format string as the iterator advances](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.0/src/chrono/format/strftime.rs.html#162-326).

Instead, I would suggest that you collect the results from that iterator to a  `Vec<Item<'static>>`.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;
extern crate chrono;
use chrono::DateTime;
use chrono::offset::FixedOffset;
use chrono::format::{Item, Parsed, parse};
use chrono::format::strftime::StrftimeItems;

static FORMATS : &[&'static str] = &["%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%.f"];

lazy_static! {
    static ref PARSED_FORMATS : Vec<Vec<Item<'static>>> = FORMATS
        .iter()
        .map(|format| StrftimeItems::new(format).collect())
        .collect();
}

fn parse_datetime(s: &str) -> Option<DateTime<FixedOffset>> {
    for format in PARSED_FORMATS.iter() {
        let mut parsed = Parsed::new();
        let dt = parse(&mut parsed, &s, format.iter().cloned())
            .and_then(|_| parsed.to_datetime() );
        if dt.is_ok() {
            return dt.ok()
        }
    }
    return None
}
```

Now, when we call `parse`, we pass `format.iter().cloned()`. `format` is a `Vec<Item<'static>>`, `iter()` produces a fresh iterator over references to the `Item`s, and `cloned()` adapts the iterator so that each `Item` is returned by value (achieved by cloning them) rather than by reference (because `parse` expects an iterator over `Item` values, not `Item` references).